# Cannot GET /file.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, get, server

I've been working with nodejs for the past days and i'm stuck on trying to run it somehow.
This is what i did:
1.Create a file.js with this code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var Chance = require('chance');

var chance = new Chance();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if (chance.integer({min: 1, max: 10}) == 1) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/file1.js'));
    } else {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/file2.js'));
    }
});

app.listen(80);
```

2.Created the file1 and file2 javascripts(Each contain a window.alert
3.Started nginx with the config like this:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

But whenever i go to Ip/file.js it says:
Cannot GET /file.js

Obviously i did node file.js and started nginx!!!
Why am i getting that?!

Comment: Both your nginx and node.js server listening on port 80?

Comment: Um,yes?! Is it wrong?!

Comment: You can't have both on same port, that's impossible. You probably didn't run you node script or your nginx didn't run.

Comment: Well i'm quite sure that the nodejs is running.I can't say the same thing for nginx although i didn't get any error at doing it at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not serving the file at `ip/file.js`, you're serving it at `ip/`. Your route is defined here:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) { ... });
```

The filename of the script has no bearing on what address you access it from. To get the result you're expecting, the route definition would have to look something like this:

```
app.get('/file.js', function(req, res) { ... });
```

Comment: Oh my...gosh yeah you're right!!! Also i've typed sendFIle
it should've been sendFile
Thnx mate! That clearly helped me alot!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Could you mark the answer as accepted if this sorted it for you?

Comment: Just one question.Can I make that only certain domain/IP can get the response from the file?!

Comment: @JMon - You can access the IP and hostname from `req.ip` and `req.hostname` and then compare that to a list of allowed values in the route handler - although of course, these could feasibly be faked by someone, so whether this is secure enough depends on what you're using it for.